# Notification is not working in the Chrome Extension I am making

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to create chrome extensions.

But I don't get the notification as I expected using Chrome Notification API's

```
 chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'total': newTotal },function(){
                if (amount && newTotal >= budget.limit){
                    var notifOptions = {
                        type : 'basic',
                        iconUrl : 'logo48.png',
                        title : 'Limit reached!',
                        message : 'Uh oh ! Looks like you reached your limit!'
                    };
                chrome.notifications.create('limitNotif',notifOptions,function(id) { console.log("Last error:", chrome.runtime.lastError); }) ;
                }

            });
```

When I press a button called `spend` this notification is supposed to pop up.

The permissions for notifications are enabled in Chrome

You can find the full project and file [here](https://github.com/gopinav/Chrome-Extensions/blob/09d50a5d4632f3513e5adf74cb8aab36bdce8cb7/BudgetManager/popup.js)

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me what is the problem. Debug it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm The console.log inside the call back function prints it into the console , but I still don't get the notification .

Comment: @wOxxOm fixed it , the notification access to chrome was disabled in windows . Turned it back on .